# I am not able to remove error - Error: syntax error found at EOF in the following program

Tags: sml

```
signature Algebra =

sig

    datatype Symex =  ICOEFF of int
        | COEFF of string
        | VAR of string
        | POWER of Symex * int
        | NEG of Symex
        | PLUS of Symex * Symex
        | MULT of Symex * Symex
    val showSymex : Symex -> unit
end;


structure EXPR : Expression =
    struct
        datatype Symex =  ICOEFF of int
        | COEFF of string
        | VAR of string
        | POWER of Symex * int
        | NEG of Symex
        | PLUS of Symex * Symex
        | MULT of Symex * Symex


fun showSymex("")= ""
    | showSymex(PLUS (x,y)) = "(" ^ showSymex(x) ^ " + " ^ showSymex(y) ^ ")"
    | showSymex(MULT (x,y)) = "(" ^ showSymex(x) ^ " * " ^ showSymex(y) ^ ")"
    | showSymex(ICOEFF (x)) = "(" ^ showSymex(x) ^ ")"
    | showSymex(VAR  (x) )  = "(" ^ showSymex(x) ^ ")"
    | showSymex(COEFF (x))  = "(" ^ showSymex(x) ^ ")"
    | showSymex(POWER(x,y)) = "(" ^ showSymex(x) ^ " ^ " ^ showSymex(y) ^ ")"
    | showSymex(NEG (x,y) ) = "(" ^  "-" ^ showSymex(x) ^ ")"
    | showSymex(x)      = a;
```

Answer (score 2):

You forget to close your structure with an `end`.
Also, you give the wrong name for your signature (`Expression` instead of `Algebra`) when declaring the structure.

```
structure EXPR : Algebra =
struct
    (* contents of structure *)
end (* <- this was missing *)
```